# Ending a for loop when a string is empty

Tags: c++

So I have a function that calls a string and I am converting the string into an int array.

```
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
    areaIntA[i] = area[i] - '0';
    areaCounter++;
}
```

before I had it was for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) because 5 was the max limit for my int array, but I had problems with that. How can I make the condition end the for loop when the string has no more values left, because sometimes it might call "50" or "540" or "1" or "1930" etc...

Comment: What type of strings? Can you give a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; area[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    areaIntA[i] = area[i] - '0';
    areaCounter++;
}
```

Comment: @asifsid88 after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

switch(stringType)

case `std::string`:

```
for (i = 0; i<area.length() ; i++)
{
```

case `char*`:

```
for (i = 0; area[i] != '\0' ; i++)
{
```

case fixed length `char[]`:

```
for (i = 0; i< sizeof(area)/sizeof(area[0]) ; i++)
{
```